# Force commands from one package over those of another?

Tags: macros, packages

I'm trying to use package fuzz (not standard) with the ACM conference class.  I'm running into a lot of conflicts, e.g. Command \lbag, \rbag, \emptyset ... already defined.  How can I force my package over the acm commands?  (Assuming both print the same) but the use of my package has semantic properties for another preprocessor.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{fuzz}
```

! LaTeX Error: Command `\lbag' already defined.

Note: the fuzz package is available here: https://bitbucket.org/Spivey/fuzz/src/default/tex/fuzz.sty

Comment: Where's `fuzz.sty` available?

Comment: @egreg just added a link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\undef{}`  command from `etoolbox` package to make all conflicting command undef before loading the `fuzz` package.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\undef{\lbag}
% same for the other conflicting commands

\usepackage{fuzz}
\begin{document}
$\lbag$

\end{document}
```